# Get the total of value in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm creating a report using Crystal Report that required to total the amount but I'm having a problem since there was a same value and transaction number and it should be count as one.

Here is the example table.

| Transaction No1 | Amount1 | Transaction No2 | Amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100001 | 4,000 | 100005 | 3,500 |
| 100002 | 5,000 | 100006 | 4,500 |
| 100002 | 5,000 | 100007 | 500 |
| 100003 | 4,000 | 100008 | 4,000 |

In the table above, the total for the amount1 should be 13,000 and in Amount2 should be 12,500

Is there a way I can do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to group the report on Transaction No1.
Then, create a Running Total and elect to 'Evaluate' on change of group.

Or, if you know the data is sorted by Transaction No1 you can simply Evaluate on change of field.
[image: creating a Running Total]